# c# - Yes / No value of System

Tags: c#

Is there a way I can get the Yes / No value of the System Language in the .Net framework?

I don´t want to make language files for each language when I only need Yes & no...

Comment: You only need "Yes" and "No"? What will you be asking that requires a "Yes/No" answer using only "Yes" and "No"?

Comment: The question can be defined by the user. That´s the problem ^^

Comment: Sooo, the only part of your entire application that needs translation is Yes / No?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I´ve found a solution:

```
class Program {
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, uint uID, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nBufferMax);
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);    
        IntPtr user32 = LoadLibrary(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\User32.dll");
        LoadString(user32, 805, sb, sb.Capacity);
        YES = sb.ToString().Replace("&","");
        LoadString(user32, 806, sb, sb.Capacity);
        NO = sb.ToString().Replace("&","");
    }            
    public static string YES;
    public static string NO;
}
```

Comment: Cool - you're using `.Substring(1)` to chop off the `&` though. This identifies the keyboard shortcut and might not always be on the first character. (But I expect it would, except if there was a language where yes and no began with the same letter.) It might be safer to `.Replace("&","")` instead.

Comment: Nice to see, you could solve your problem. Notice that the function `GetModuleHandle` is cheaper than a `LoadLibrary`, but i'm not sure you can use it in Dotnet. Anyway, in contrast to `GetModuleHandle`, a `LoadLibrary` needs a `FreeLibrary` afterwards.

Comment: I could write a small example in CSharp using GetModuleHandle, have a look at my first post.

Answer (score 10):

You can indeed use the windows resources.

I once made an example (unfortunately in Delphi), but you can surely do it in Dotnet as well. It can be really useful, you are not limited to "Yes" and "No", but can use phrases like "do you want to continue...".

http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/delphi/delphi.html#StringWindowsRes

Sorry that i can't provide an example in C#.

Edit: Well, now i found the time to write a small class in C#:

```
internal static class StoWindowsString
{
  /// <summary>
  ///   Searches for a text resource in a Windows library.
  ///   Sometimes, using the existing Windows resources, you can
  ///   make your code language independent and you don't have to
  ///   care about translation problems.
  /// </summary>
  /// <example>
  ///   btnCancel.Text = StoWindowsString.Load("user32.dll", 801, "Cancel");
  ///   btnYes.Text = StoWindowsString.Load("user32.dll", 805, "Yes");
  /// </example>
  /// <param name="LibraryName">Name of the windows library like
  ///   "user32.dll" or "shell32.dll"</param>
  /// <param name="Ident">Id of the string resource.</param>
  /// <param name="DefaultText">Return this text, if the resource
  ///   string could not be found.</param>
  /// <returns>Desired string if the resource was found, otherwise
  ///   the DefaultText</returns>
  public static string Load(string libraryName, uint Ident, string DefaultText)
  {
    IntPtr libraryHandle = GetModuleHandle(libraryName);
    if (libraryHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
      int size = LoadString(libraryHandle, Ident, sb, 1024);
      if (size > 0)
        return sb.ToString();
      else
        return DefaultText;
    }
    else
    {
      return DefaultText;
    }
  }

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
  private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  private static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, uint uID, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nBufferMax);
}
```

Comment: You can find Yes and No as string resources in user32.dll, although they'll have keyboard shortcut markers: "&Yes" and "&No"

Answer (score 3):

You could take a Universal Approach and use pictures.

[image]
[image]
[image]

You could make your own, ignoring the use of the words shown in two of the images above and go with the Check and X images. I use this for our factory workers who are not only mostly illiterate but sometimes non-English speaking.

Comment: Unfortunately few things are culturally universal. For instance, us Finnish people learn to mark the correct answer with an "X", and the tick mark is actually used to mark *incorrect* answers when grading tests. Green and red buttons are inaccessible for people with some forms of color blindness. Nodding and shaking one's head are mostly universal, but I've heard there are cultures where the meanings are different. If we consider illiterate people (likely not exposed to other cultures than their own), coming from any place in the world, it's not safe to assume anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
  public static class YesNo{


       public static string GetYesOrNo(this bool boolean)
       {
           var dictionary = boolean ? _yesDictionary : _noDictionary;
           if(dictionary.ContainsKey(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName))
           {
               return dictionary[CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName];
           }
           return boolean ? DEFAULT_YES : DEFAULT_NO;
       }

      const string DEFAULT_YES = "yes";
      const string DEFAULT_NO = "no";

      private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _yesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                                                              {
                                                                                  {"en","yes"},
                                                                                  {"de", "ja"},
                                                                                  {"es", "si"}
                                                                              };
      private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _noDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                                                             {
                                                                                 {"en", "no"},
                                                                                 {"de", "nein"},
                                                                                 {"es", "no"}
                                                                             };

  }
```

Comment: So when the OP say that he does not want to use language files for each language, you think that it is better to hard-code the language values in the code?

Answer (score 0):

This could also be a case for using localized resource files for looking up translated values.