# How to generically format a boolean to a Yes/No string?

Tags: c#, formatting, coding-style, string-formatting

I would like to display Yes/No in different languages according to some boolean variable.
Is there a generic way to format it according to the locale passed to it?
If there isn't, what is the standard way to format a boolean besides `boolVar ? Resources.Yes : Resources.No`.
I'm guessing that `boolVar.ToString(IFormatProvider)` is involved.
Is my assumption correct?

Comment: What type of application winform, asp.net .... ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Does it matter? It's the framework that causes this issue. It's ASP.NET MVC in this case but might as well be winforms or WPF later.

Comment: You can find the localized version of Yes/No in user32.dll : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5577735/200443

Comment: I created a uservoice for this [go vote for it](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5748267-allow-custom-format-strings-for-boolean-values)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The framework itself does not provide this for you (as far as I know). Translating `true/false` into `yes/no` does not strike me as more common than other potential translations (such as `on/off`, `checked/unchecked`, `read-only/read-write` or whatever).

I imagine that the easiest way to encapsulate the behavior is to make an extension method that wraps the construct that you suggest yourself in your question:

```
public static class BooleanExtensions
{
    public static string ToYesNoString(this bool value)
    {
        return value ? Resources.Yes : Resources.No;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
bool someValue = GetSomeValue();
Console.WriteLine(someValue.ToYesNoString());
```

Comment: I am already doing that but I wondered if there's a better solution.

Comment: For nullable bools add this overload to the class:         

public static string ToYesNoString(this bool? value)
        {
            return value.HasValue ? value.Value.ToYesNoString() : String.Empty;
        }

Answer (score 57):

As the other answers indicate, the framework does not allow boolean values to have custom formatters. However, it does allow for numbers to have custom formats. The GetHashCode method on the boolean will return 1 for true and 0 for false.

According to [MSDN Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator), when there are 3 sections of ";" the specified format will be applied to "positive numbers;negative numbers;zero".

The GetHashCode method can be called on the bool value to return a number so you can use the Custom Numeric Format String to return Yes/No or On/Off or any other set of words the situation calls for.

Here is a sample that returns on/OFF:

```
var truth   = string.Format("{0:on;0;OFF}", true.GetHashCode());
var unTruth = string.Format("{0:on;0;OFF}", false.GetHashCode());
```

returns:

```
truth   = on
unTruth = OFF
```

Comment: That's a really nice trick but it's hackish so I am keeping the accepted answer in place. Thank you very much.

Comment: Less hackish than GetHashCode() is to use Convert.ToInt32(value); it will also return 0 and 1.

Comment: +1: in ASP.NET this trick can be done in `FormatString` properties, like `GridView` `BoundField.DataFormatString`. Just add a Byte (or Int16 or Int32, etc) property to the Model that return a numeric conversion of the bool value. That's it. Many thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8126 Allow custom format strings for boolean values. This issue is currently tagged for "Future" milestone.

Comment: The code for [`Boolean.GetHashCode()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs,80) is just `value ? 1 : 0`, so you're just adding more condition evaluations by using it. I don't see the point. (you'd never notice a difference in speed, it's just more confusing and no benefit)

Comment: This trick is a useful performance improver for Analysis Services Tabular models that use the same format string technology. Less data over the wire to be formatted efficiently by the .net format string by the client. A good hack!.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, [Boolean.ToString(IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s802ct92.aspx) does not help here:

> The *provider* parameter is reserved. It does not participate in the execution of this method. This means that the Boolean.ToString(IFormatProvider) method, unlike most methods with a *provider* parameter, does not reflect culture-specific settings.

In any case, Booleans represent True and False, not Yes and No. If you want to map True -> Yes and False -> No, you will have to do that (including localization) yourself; there's no built-in support in the framework for that. Your propopsed solution (Resources.Yes/No) looks fine to me.

Answer (score 8):

in my razor page is working this: 
`@(item.Active.GetValueOrDefault() ? "Yes" : "No")`

here is important if attribute is required (nullable) or not, if is required it should be good with:

```
@(item.Active ? "Yes":"No")
```

I found this here on some other post, just replaying, hope it helps some1.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  Used it in my controller for an excel extract.   sw.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\" ... ", item.IsCycle1 ? "1" : "", ... ))