# Displaying bool value as Yes or No

Tags: c#, boolean, oledbdatareader

I am quering a database and assigning the values to an object which I serialize and display in a report.

Thing is the bool variables are displayed in the report as true or false. How can get the values to be displayed as "Yes" or "No".

This is my class

```
public class ProductReportView
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
    public string Producer { get; set; }

    public bool VideoOnDemand { get; set; }
    public bool PreviewScreen { get; set; }
    public bool QualityCheck { get; set; }
    public bool Archive { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I assign the values

```
OleDbDataReader dbreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dbreader.Read())
{
     Console.WriteLine("Record " + totalCount++);
     ProductReportView rep = new ProductReportView();
     rep.Count = ++totalCount;
     rep.ProductCode = (string)dbreader["CODE"];
     rep.ProductTitle = (string)dbreader["TITLE"];
     rep.Producer = (string)dbreader["PRODUCER"];
     rep.VideoOnDemand = (bool)dbreader["VideoOnDemand"];
     rep.PreviewScreen = (bool)dbreader["PreviewLibraryChecked"];
     rep.QualityCheck = (bool)dbreader["QualityCheck"];
     rep.Archive = (bool)dbreader["Archive"];
     lst.Add(rep);
}
```

The values are based on checkboxes that is checked and unchecked(VideoOnDemand, PreviewScreen QualityCheck, Archive)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632920/how-to-generically-format-a-boolean-to-a-yes-no-string - have a look

Comment: `display in a report`  Where and how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use ternary operator while storing your value in the object

```
rep.VideoOnDemand = (bool)dbreader["VideoOnDemand"] ? "Yes" : "No";
```

And make `VideoOnDemand` as `string`

```
public string VideoOnDemand { get; set; }
```

use the same approach for rest of the variables for which you need YES/ NO

Comment: I don't think that is very good practice to save it as a String. It might be useful in the future to still store it as a Boolean. This is a presentation problem.

Answer (score 5):

You don't say how you are 'reporting'...

Does this help?

```
   Control.Text = rep.VideoOnDemand ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Answer (score 2):

Making changes during storing the value in object is really a bad idea. So do it at the C# level in the grid

```
Control.Text = rep.VideoOnDemand ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this in your Sql Query also.

Eg.

Select

case VideoOnDemand
when 1 then 'YES'
else 'NO'
end as 'VideoOnDemand'

from tblxyz

Answer (score 0):

My approach, with 4 simple properties, gives reusability and cleaning the code:

```
public class ProductReportView
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductTitle { get; set; }
    public string Producer { get; set; }

    public bool VideoOnDemand { get; set; }
    public bool PreviewScreen { get; set; }
    public bool QualityCheck { get; set; }
    public bool Archive { get; set; }

    private string toYesNo(bool b)
    {
        return b ? "Yes" : "No";
    }

    public string VideoOnDemandString
    {
        get { return this.toYesNo(this.VideoOnDemand); }
    }

    public string PreviewScreenString
    {
        get { return this.toYesNo(this.PreviewScreen); }
    }

    public string QualityCheckString
    {
        get { return this.toYesNo(this.QualityCheck); }
    }

    public string ArchiveString
    {
        get { return this.toYesNo(this.Archive); }
    }
}
```

This code can be reused in all your application without repetitions of "yes", "no", "yes", "no", etc.

Final suggestion: bools should be stored in bool properties, strings should be stored in string properties.

Don't persist bool values converted to string: don't have any sense.