# Use IF statement in Lambda Expression C#

Tags: c#, lambda

I've been trying to use if statment in a lambda expression instead of the ternary operator in C# as that is what I am instructed to do. I did try a few things but then it still gives me an error. Can anyone help me with this problem?

This is my code:

```
//name: DisplayData
//data in: none
//data out: string that contains the id, name, tuition, and FT or PT based on fulltime status
//description: format with tabs between. Use conditional IF and lambda operator
public string DisplayData() => id + "\t" + name + "\t" + (if(fulltime == true) "FT";
    else "PT";) + "\t" + tuition.ToString("c");
```

Comment: What is wrong with classic and more readable function definition?

Comment: That's not a lambda, that's just an expression bodied member.

Comment: please format your code properly and be as _unambiguous_ as possible.

Comment: I have a feeling you've been told to ditch the expression bodied method for a traditionally defined one, but that's just a guess because unclear.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a lambda expression there, you have an expression bodied member, which is to say you've specifically indicated that you're going to use an *expression* rather than a *statement* as the definition of the method.

An `if` statement is, as the name implies, a statement.  It's not an expression.  If you want to use a *statement* as the body of your method then you can't use an expression bodied member, you'll need to use the more traditional syntax for defining a method.  Additionally, you're using the actual `if` statement itself as an expression within the expression bodied member; the `if` statement *doesn't resolve to a value* because it's not an expression, so you can't use it as if it has a value.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot avoid ternary operator, because you cannot use [*statements* inside *expressions*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173142.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

You can use a conditional expression to construct the value that you need. Also consider using string interpolation syntax for better readability:

```
public string DisplayData() => $"{id}\t{name}\t{(fulltime ? "FT" : "PT")}\t{tuition:c}";
```

Alternatively, you could use a [formatting trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10435526/335858) for numbers to format your `bool` value by using its hash code:

```
public string DisplayData() => $"{id}\t{name}\t{fulltime.GetHashCode():FT;0;PT}\t{tuition:c}"
```

Comment: Im fairly sure you need parenthesis around the ternary inside a string interpolation.   `public string DisplayData() => $"{id}\t{name}\t{(fulltime ? "FT" : "PT")}\t{tuition:c}";`    This should't build as you have it.

Comment: @Botonomous Oops, sorry, I copied your code into VS, that's why I didn't see an error. Thank you!