# Convert all bit data type column value into Yes / No value in a data table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable, bit

I am looking to convert 1s and 0s to Yes and No in a data table using C# for only columns that are of type bit in SQL Server.

```
ActiveFlag    =>      ActiveFlag
----------            ----------
    1                      Yes
    0                      No
```

Is there a way to achieve this?
I am using C# with SQL Server 2014.

I am open to converting all bit values to Yes/No in SQL Server as well. (Select the columnn value after conversion). However I cannot use hard coded field names as the columns are dynamic and may vary from time to time. So something like

```
CASE WHEN ActiveFlag= 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Active
```

is not an option I can use. ActiveFlag column may never exist tomorrow and can be replaced with an entirely new column.

Thanks

Edit 1:

I only used the isMale example because I've come across that example in another question on SO.

I am also open to using sql to dynamically parse value and convert based on its data type.

Changed IsMale example to relate to column.

Comment: We're in 2017. a boolean for a gender? Unless it isn't for people.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want to achieve: are you working on a C# Winform app? However, you could dynamically parse your SQL query and decide - basing on the column data type - if you want to use 'yes / no'... anyways, please explain a bit more in detail what you want to achieve.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632920/how-to-generically-format-a-boolean-to-a-yes-no-string

Comment: You should not be doing this on the data side. This is a presentation issue and should be handled in the front end.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen It is just an example. That column is not at all a part of my query.

Comment: @Tyron78 I have a bunch of fields of datatype bit in SQL Server that I want to retrieve as Yes/No instead of 1/0. Hope that clears it up a bit?

Comment: What is your C# app using to read the data? You can iterate over all the columns in your data table or whatever, and check for data type...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.aspx

Comment: Bit is the boolean type on databases.

Comment: @Gusman the bit datatype is not a boolean. It can contain 3 values (0, 1, NULL). There is no datatype in sql server that functions like a boolean but bit is the closest we can get.

Comment: @SeanLange It can contain three values if you set it as nullable, like a boolean.

Comment: @Gusman I think you mean not null. But regardless it still is not a true boolean. It is a datatype that can contain 2 values at that point. You still can't use as a true boolean. Regardless I am pretty sure the OP gets that, they want to display the string values "Yes" and "No".

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, i meant not null, :) Anyway what I meant is that you will use it as a boolean, the user wants to present "Yes", then the same code you can use with a "true" boolean can be used.