# How to convert boolean to string?

Tags: c#

Greeting. I would like to create a program that prints the data on the console via the entered data in the object (name, surname, hobby, profession, whether the person is married, etc.). However it always tells me true or false as to whether the person is married. I would like to create it to print YES or NO and not true or false. The question is: Is there any way to print YES or NO to me instead of true or false? I want to convert Boolean to string and here is the code

```
namespace aplikacija;

public class podaci
{  public string ime , Last_name, job, hobby;
   public int years;
   public bool married;
   const  bool YES = true ;
   const  bool NO = false;
   public void  write()
   {
        Console.WriteLine("My first name is  " + ime + 
            ". My last name is  " + Last_name + "" +
            ". My job is " + job + ". My hobby is " + hobby + 
            ". I am " + years + " years old" + ". Married: " + married);
   }
}

class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {                              
        podaci person = new podaci();
        person.ime = "John";
        person.Last_name = " Smith ";
        person.job = " Elektrician ";
        person.hobby = " Kickbox ";
        person.years = 24;
        person.married = true;
        person.write();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: string marriedString= married?"Yes":"No";

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generically format a boolean to a Yes/No string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632920/how-to-generically-format-a-boolean-to-a-yes-no-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)?

```
Console.WriteLine("My first name is  " + ime + 
            ". My last name is  " + Last_name + "" +
            ". My job is " + job + ". My hobby is " + hobby + 
            ". I am " + years + " years old" + ". Married: " + (married? "yes" : "no"));
```

You could likewise add a property to `Podaci` the renders this as a string:

```
public class Podaci
{
    public string ime, lastName, job, hobby;
    public int years;
    public bool married;
    
    public string MarriedString => married?"Yes":"No";
    
    public void  Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My first name is  " + ime + 
            ". My last name is  " + lastName + "" +
            ". My job is " + job + ". My hobby is " + hobby + 
            ". I am " + years + " years old" + ". Married: " + MarriedString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ternary Operator

```cs
string yesno = person.married ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider combining the use of the ternary operator with string interpolation:

```
Console.WriteLine($"My first name is  {ime}. My last name is  {Last_name}. My job is {job}. My hobby is {hobby}. I am {years} years old. Married: {(married ? "yes" : "no")}");
```